Curve bevel object on complex shape - corners and curve issues

So I'm trying to model this fireplace surround. I've used a curve, then in the data tab applied bevel to an object (the profile seen in the picture under the surround).

Is there anyway to fix the corners and make it look clean?
I've tried constructing the model manually from scratch with offset edges, but that never looks quite right - lots of distortion on the curvey part of the surround. I need all the different parts to maintain their width and distance from eachother.
I also tried converting the curve with the bevel object on to a mesh, and then manually reposition all the edges, but still: distortion.
Reducing the amount of vertices on the curve also didn't fix that problem.
I have yet to try the spin tool, but I thought I'd ask first before I spend any more hours trying to figure this one out.
Is there any way to model this in a non-destructive way? And if I need to be destructive, how to best tackle the distancing and width between the different parts?
